# Sun T2000 SC Log file

Tags: log-files, sun

Is there a SC log file for the Sun T2000?

I'm hoping to track down a possible power problem.  So if you have any suggestions outside of a log file... that would be great.

What makes me think its a power problem is that the T2000 turns off frequently.  We'll come back from the weekend and it will be sitting at the "ok>" prompt.

Thanks!

Comment: I've answered your question directly, but you may get a better answer if you explain why you think you have a possible power problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a few things you can look at in the SC.

1. Show a summary of component status: `sc> showenvironment`
2. Show the last 100 lines of the console history: `sc> consolehistory -e 100`
3. Show the last 100 lines of the SC event history: `sc> showlogs -e 100`
4. Show the hardware information, including event logs for many components: `sc> showfru`

In addition, Solaris itself keeps track of potential problems using FMA (Fault Management Architecture).

1. See if Solaris has diagnosed an issue: `# fmadm faulty`
2. Show the low level telemetry that may contribute to a fault status: `# fmdump -e` and `# fmdump -eV`
3. Of course, check the log files such as `/var/adm/messages` as well.